# Synthesis methods of inorganic materials

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

On our exams we are asked to determine which synthesis method is best suited for a given compound. We have discussed direct synthesis methods such as high temp. and ampull, and indirect synthesis methods such as solvothermal, sol-gel, and ion exchange.

I thought that the direct high temperature synthesis was mostly used for compounds with three or more elements such as $\ce{BaTiO3}$. However, in our exam the compound $\ce{Fe3O4}$ is said to be synthesized by the direct high temperature method.

For example, one question states:

> Propose and motivate two methods (each) of synthesis of $\ce{NaAlSiO4}$ and $\ce{Cu(CN)(pyr)2}$

I believe one method for $\ce{NaAlSiO4}$ should be direct high temp. because that method is applicable for aluminosilicates but have no idea what the second one could be. Is there a specific way to determine the synthesis methods of different compounds just by looking at them?

All help is truly appreciated!

Comment: I'd say, no, it's impossible to say which method exactly would work the best, you can only make general assumptions such as organic ligands or hydroxo-salts won't survive a high-temperature synthesis. Metal oxides, on the other hand, can be synthesized by a variety of low- and high-temp methods and their combinations (see e.g. Pechini method).

Comment: The synthesis method depends on your preferred starting material. What do you propose for both of them?

Comment: @Karl For Cu(CN)(pyr)$_2$ I don't really have any idea on what the methods could be. For NaAlSiO$_4$ the starting materials would be NaAlO$_2$ and SiO$_2$. How does that help determine the method?

Comment: Your list of methods has a few missing, e.g. precipitation from solution and transport reaction in a temperature gradient.

Comment: Yup. Both NaAlO2 and SiO2 have very high melting points. Do you have an oven and crucible that goes that high? I say no. So you need to get the necessary temperature *down*. Ideas? And the starting materials for the other one are rather obvious, think simple!

Comment: @Karl I only listed the methods we have discussed in class. So for NaAlSiO$_4$ I should not use high temperature methods but low? Maybe, Cu(CN) and (pyr)$_2$ then?

Comment: You are not doing this systematically. High/lo temp. is totally insufficient to categorise those methods. You cant do the alsilicate in the melt. You cant do it at STP in solution, because everything is dead insoluble. Solid state would take centuries. How can you get oxides in solution?